Can't transfer file via tftp, ERROR - Failed to open file 'file' on server
The Debian computer connected to router, router connected to a modem, router ip 192.168.10.1, modem IP addr 192.168.100.1 and computer IP addr 192.168.10.106.  I want to transfer file from modem IP to TFTP Server(tftp-hpa) running on computer. I'm always getting an error "Failed to open file 'file.bin' on server ...!" I assume, this error is typically caused by a firewall blocking access. But firewall on Debian computer is inactive,sudo ufw status verbose => Status: inactive I can ping modem from computer, but pinging computer from modem not getting a response (No reply after 5000 ms....)
It could be also the router firewall issue, but it has port 69 specified for tftp in Port Forwarding Rules, so firewall should allow TFTP requests through port 69. Should the modem and computer to be in the same network for tftp transfer? I tried manually configure ip on debian computer instead of DHCP (within the same ip range), but this not help. How to solve this issue?
Opening file 'file.bin' on 192.168.10.106 for writing...
    [01:45:20 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::GetReply:  (Tftp Client) Timed out on socket select!
    [01:45:20 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::Send:  (Tftp Client) Attempt #(1) Backoff (2) Exp Block #(0) Last Block #(0) Recv'd Block #(0)
    [01:45:24 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::GetReply:  (Tftp Client) Timed out on socket select!
    [01:45:24 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::Send:  (Tftp Client) Attempt #(2) Backoff (4) Exp Block #(0) Last Block #(0) Recv'd Block #(0)
    [01:45:32 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::GetReply:  (Tftp Client) Timed out on socket select!
    [01:45:32 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::Send:  (Tftp Client) Attempt #(3) Backoff (8) Exp Block #(0) Last Block #(0) Recv'd Block #(0)
    ... ... ...
    [01:48:44 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::Send:  (Tftp Client) Attempt #(15) Backoff (16) Exp Block #(0) Last Block #(0) Recv'd Block #(0)
    [01:49:00 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::GetReply:  (Tftp Client) Timed out on socket select!
    [01:49:00 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::Send:  (Tftp Client) Attempt #(16) Backoff (16) Exp Block #(0) Last Block #(0) Recv'd Block #(0)
    [01:49:16 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::GetReply:  (Tftp Client) Timed out on socket select!
    [01:49:16 06/24/2024] [ConsoleThread] Tftp Client::Send:  (Tftp Client) ERROR - Request Retries > kTftpMaxRequestRetryCount (16) !
    ERROR - Failed to open file 'file.bin' on server 192.168.10.106!

EDIT: I resolved the issue. The solution was to use public IP address of computer.

please add answer to the question and accept it 24h later, else it will not be marked as solved

The issue is resolved. The solution was to use a public IP address of computer for tftp write, not private IP address.
